# Using Boto3 how to check if AWS policy has been updated?

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda, boto3

Thanks in advance!

I need to check if a particular Policy has been updated since it is created in AWS using Boto3.

I am not able to find any modified parameter for a policy to check if it is modified or not.

Can we use Version in policy as a parameter to check if it modified or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get a new version in the list of versions, so you answered this yourself.
https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Policy.versions